# How to set value back to Alpine Variable alpine directive?

Tags: alpine.js

I want to make a alpine plugin can be click for select file and return file had select to a variable.

```
#html
<button x-select="photo">
    <span>Upload</span>
</button>

#script
Alpine.data('UpdateProfile', () => ({
    photo: null,
}));

#alpine directive
Alpine.directive(
    "select",
    (el, { value, expression }, { effect, evaluateLater }) => {
        el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "file";
            input.accept = "*";
            input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
                const file = e.target.files;
            });
            input.click();
        });
    }
);
```

How I can set `e.target.files` to `photo` alpine variable.

Comment: have you considered using Alpine.store ?

Comment: @pthomson I just want to make a directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create a JS expression, that set the value of the user provided data name to the uploaded file name, then [evaluate](https://alpinejs.dev/advanced/extending#evaluating-expressions) this expression within the Alpine.js context. For example, if the filename is `picture.jpg`, then `${expression} = '${file[0].name}'` expression becomes `photo = 'picture.jpg'`, so Alpine.js sets `photo` to the filename.

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.directive(
    "select",
    (el, { value, expression }, { evaluate }) => {
      el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const input = document.createElement("input")
        input.type = "file"
        input.accept = "*"
        input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
          const file = e.target.files
          evaluate(`${expression} = '${file[0].name}'`)
        })
        input.click()
      })
    }
  )
})
```